# How do I find old chocolatey package versions, for specification in the chocolatey package.config

Tags: nuget, chocolatey

I like to use chocolatey to configure personal additions to my dev workstations. For some  packages I do not want the current version. A specific example is that I want ruby 1.9.3, while the current chocolatey. Other packaging systems, [such as bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html), provide a simple way to enforce this.

I can find the current version of a package with `chocolatey version putty`

and put that in my package.config

```
<packages>
<package id="putty" version="0.63" />
</packages>
```

But, I don't know how to find available packages. Thus, the question: How do I find old chocolatey package versions, for specification in the chocolatey package.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would type

```
choco search ruby -all
```

Comment: Thanks! That is missing from choco help, but I see it in the wiki now.

Comment: You can also specify exact (`-e`) package name as follows:
`choco search -e ruby -a`

Or, check version history through web: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/chocolatey#versionhistory